# How to schedule Spark jobs on Google Dataproc?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to create an ingestion/aggregation flow on Google Cloud using Dataproc, where once a day/hour I want a Spark job to run on the data collected till then.

Is there any way to schedule the Spark jobs? Or of making this trigger based for e.g. on any new data event arriving on the flow?

Comment: Did you find the way which you need

Comment: @HashanMalawana Henry's answer is good for scheduling and for triggering we can use Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thank you I will see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dataproc Workflow + Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/workflow-scheduler) might be a solution for you. It supports exactly what you described, e.g. run a flow of jobs in a daily base.